# How can I draw straight route between two points and escape obstacles?

Tags: algorithm, math, canvas, routes

I want to draw path between two points and there are some rectangular obstacles on there. The routes must be made with straight line segments.
There might be a algorithm for it.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it, including a code attempt. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what the problem is, what you expected, what you got, and any error messages.

Comment: Also, your question is not quite clear. Do you mean that each route must be a series of straight line segments (called a polyline)? Must the route be the shortest possible? What is no route is possible? What exactly is the input format and what exactly is the output format?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
Navigating a path in the "blocks world" has been covered well for at least 50 years.  Try "robot navigate blocks 'artificial intelligence'" as a search start.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea:

1. Draw a straight line as the first line segment.
2. Check if any line segment hits a rectangle.  (If not, then you are done.)
3. If any one does, replace the line segment with two line segments which go to the closer of the two corners of the rectangle which mean going around it.
4. Repeat with step 2.

Here you can see three iterations (red → green → blue) of this process.

[image]

Of course, this is just a crude idea on how to get started.  It will not work for intersecting rectangles (thanks, @sneftel) or for rectangles which aren't completely inside the area, and it also isn't sure to find an optimal solution in the simple cases.

To get the optimal path I guess the only option would be to go through all possible combinations of rectangle corners (with some possible optimizations).

Comment: That won't work if the rectangular obstacles intersect each other.

Answer (score 0):

In the best path, if there is one, every line segment starts and ends at the start point, the end point, or a corner of a rectangular obstacle.

You can use the A* algorithm on the graph of these points to find the shortest path, where two points are connected by an edge in the graph if the line between them doesn't cross any obstacles.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm